# SqlQuery in Azure Function ARRAY_CONTAINS not work

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I defined a function in cosmo db defined as follows. In the editor the query works but when I run the function it return *500 Internal Server Error*.

My document:

```
{
    "user": "428",
    "year": "2019",
    "id": "1",
    "dataType": "LineString",
    "dataCategory": "realPath",
    "tripNumber": "A02232",
    "currentCoordinate": [
        13.845224,
        43.02356
    ],
    "deliveries": [
        {
            "devNumber": "001",
            "unloadSeq": "1",
            "currentDev": "1",
            "email": "punto1@mail.it",
            "targetCoordinate": [
                13.965224,
                43.95356
            ],
            "coordinates": [
                [
                    13.790663,
                    43.028926
                ],
                [
                    13.791447,
                    43.029169
                ],
                [
                    13.792198,
                    43.029561
                ],
                [
                    13.793775,
                    43.030549
                ],
                [
                    13.794601,
                    43.0312
                ],
                [
                    13.795577,
                    43.031835
                ],
                [
                    13.797047,
                    43.032737
                ],
                [
                    13.797605,
                    43.033153
                ],
                [
                    13.798249,
                    43.033647
                ],
                [
                    13.798732,
                    43.03367
                ],
                [
                    13.800126,
                    43.033678
                ],
                [
                    13.801661,
                    43.033725
                ],
                [
                    13.802755,
                    43.034172
                ],
                [
                    13.845224,
                    43.02356
                ]
            ]
        },
        {
            "devNumber": "008",
            "unloadSeq": "2",
            "currentDev": "0",
            "email": "punto2@mail.it",
            "targetCoordinate": [
                13.995224,
                43.99356
            ],
            "coordinates": []
        }
    ],
    "_rid": "3pRjAIHZRNUBAAAAAAAAAA==",
    "_self": "dbs/3pRjAA==/colls/3pRjAIHZRNU=/docs/3pRjAIHZRNUBAAAAAAAAAA==/",
    "_etag": "\"00006b08-0000-0000-0000-5c2def460000\"",
    "_attachments": "attachments/",
    "_ts": 1546514246
}
```

Query in editor it's ok:

```
SELECT * FROM Trip c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.deliveries, {"currentDev": "1", "email": "punto1@mail.it"}, true)
```

Query in function.json don't work:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "name": "req",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "methods": [
        "get",
        "post"
      ],
      "route": "getRoutes/{emailpar}"
    },
    {
      "name": "$return",
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out"
    },
    {
      "type": "cosmosDB",
      "name": "inDocuments",
      "databaseName": "cdb-01",
      "collectionName": "myCollection",
      "connectionStringSetting": "mpn_COSMOSDB",
      "direction": "in",
      "sqlQuery": "SELECT * FROM Trip c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.deliveries, {currentDev: '1', email: {emailpar}}, true)"
    }
  ]
}
```

I think it's a syntax problem to defining the parameter and the object to be searched within the array through the brackets {}.

Comment: What is your partition key property?

Comment: There are two things that can be wrong. First I would recommend adding single quotes around the email property so many the query look like this: `SELECT * FROM Trip c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.deliveries, {currentDev: '1', email: '{emailpar}'}, true)`

Comment: Second, you probably need to escape the curly brackets that don't refer to a string interpolated property. You can *probably* do that by adding an extra curly bracket so making the string look like this: `SELECT * FROM Trip c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.deliveries, {{currentDev: '1', email: '{emailpar}'}}, true)`

Comment: Thanks @NickChapsas it works:

`SELECT * FROM Trip c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.deliveries, {{currentDev: '1', email: {emailpar}}}, true)`

My partition key are id/user but is not perfect.

I'm still trying to figure out how to choose it so you do not have hot keys

Comment: Awesome. I wrote up the answer. Please accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to escape the non parameter string interpolated object of the sql query string. You can do that by adding an extra curly brace in each reference.

This means that yous query string must be:

`SELECT * FROM Trip c where ARRAY_CONTAINS(c.deliveries, {{currentDev: '1', email: {emailpar}}}, true)`